# Calling a Movieclip from the stage from a Class

Tags: actionscript-3, class

I'm trying to call a movieclip called mcMain that's already on the stage. I'm calling it from a class and I've tried googling a whole bunch of possible solutions, none of which appear to work. I've tried stage.mcMain, this.stage.mcMain, MovieClip(root).mcMain, but nothing seems to work. Anyone got any ideas? I don't even get an error message. Just nothing happens.

Comment: what happens when you debug, put down a break point in your code that tries to call the movie clip, look through the variable inspector see if you can find your mcMain

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think that the root of your document timeline is actually the stage. However, you shouldn't be doing this. If the "Class," as you call it, is a DisplayObject, it should not know about anything outside its own scope (unless you've exposed properties or methods on it that would allow for this information to be passed in. If the Class is a data class it shouldn't know about the View at all. If it's a controller class, you'll need to pass a reference to it.

However, given the code you said you tried, I'm guessing your Class instance is some sort of DisplayObject.  What you should do is dispatch a bubbling event from your Class, and then in your main Document class, listen for that event. In the event handler function, do whatever you need to do with your mcMain instance, such as adding ketchup. This should work just fine, because your main document Class can receive events from anywhere in the display list, and mcMain is its own instance.

Comment: I think i need to go buy an AS3 book for beginners :D
Thanks though :)